# Where to install sdk components for android studio (manually)

Tags: android, sdk, installation

So the setup wizard for my android studio has downloaded some of the required sdk components but for the other ones, I have some issues with my network and it does not download them. So I manually downloaded these ones in Chrome. I extracted the .zip files in the sdk folder ( /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk ). I am not sure if this is the right location for all of them since when I run android studio again, it still wants to download a file called "android_m2repository_r47". So I believe I need to put this in another folder but I do not know where. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look for this icon in your toolbar:

[image: SDK Manager]

You can then specify your Android SDK location, as well as download and install all/part of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Unzipped sdk should be copied in `\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` folder.

It worked for me. And in `SDK Manager` you can see the installed SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you did not extract the file in a correct location as the setup wizard could not recognize it.

You need to extract "android_m2repository_r47.zip" file in `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android` folder. After extracting the zip file, you will have `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository` folder structure.

Note that, if you already find any `m2repository` folder in the `android` folder, you may need to delete the existing `m2repository` folder before extracting.